# Does MySQL have an admin-only mode?

Tags: mysql, database-migration

We need to migrate and archive some records in MySQL. We don't want to take down our entire site (most reads are serviced from a separate cache in the app layer anyway), but we need to prevent anyone from attempting to register or do anything that changes the database.

Does MySQL have a feature that puts the database into an `admin`-like mode where only the administrator can manipulate records while connections from the application layer (using a separate db account) are rejected?

Comment: How about changing the password of the account used by the application?

Comment: That's probably too harsh...I think a permission change on the user account like Nanne mentioned is a bit more graceful, also, connection pools would not react very well to a password change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `read_only` system variable. Only users with super privileges will be able to change anything.

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_read_only

Comment: Interesting, and according to the documentation, setting this property, while the server is running, blocks subsequent lock attempts until read-only is enabled, I can catch any errors on the application side after that, I think this is the easiest solution; a single property.

Answer (score 0):

You can do several things, but I don't think they are a good solution: there's a good change your applications won't react very happy to this :)

That said, you can just remove the appropriate rights from your db-user, that'll do it. They'll essentially be in read-only mode.

Check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/revoke.html on how to revoke, and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html on how to re-grant certain stuff :)

Comment: The permission change is fine, we intend to implement functionality in the app layer to catch such an exception and return a graceful error message to the end user, so that's not a problem.

Comment: Then just `revoke` some of the insert, update etc permissions